# Как изменить ось Y в графике Excel?

Tags: excel, office

Ось Y: Возраст, проблем с ним нет.
Ось X: В меню изменении ряда стоят почему то нули. 
График соответственно лежит на оси.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была в том, что перед каждым значением в столбце стоял пробел.